# Where is the appropriate place for SQL scripts in a Grails project

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I've got a Grails plugin that exports domain objects so that several applications can share the same schema. We have a few SQL scripts for setting up some complex triggers, views and other functions that just don't really belong in GORM/Hibernate, at least not elegantly. I'd like to store the scripts inside the same project. Is the "scripts" folder (the one containing _[Un]Install/Upgrade.groovy) the best place for this? I saw a StackOverflow answer that was building a catalog from scripts stored in grails-app/conf/sql. But I'm not actually trying to execute them from within the a project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The absolute best solution for anything database related is to use the [database migration plugin](https://grails.org/plugin/database-migration). This way you can ensure that any database your application is pointed to (dev, test, prod, etc.) will have the same information/schema/functions/procedures etc.

Comment: Moving to flywaydb. Similar situation. And it actually has a similar and solid suggestion. Dropping them into "/grails-app/conf/db/migrate".

Answer (score 1):

Personal preference. I usually add a 'database' dir for all that kind of stuff. The 'scripts' dir is for Grails scripts, at least in 1.x and 2.x. See [Creating Gant Scripts](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.5.0/guide/commandLine.html#creatingGantScripts) or the [create-script](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.5.0/ref/Command%20Line/create-script.html) command for more on those. In Grails 3 these kind of scripts have been moved to src/main/scripts.